# Tappable Dynamic Links With UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, uilabel

I am looking for a way, that **does not involve a `UITextView` or 3rd party framework**, to make multiple tappable links, on a label. A side note, with the string, for the label is, it’s fetched from a server, so we don’t know the links ahead of time.

As an example, lets say there’s a post, and it has two links, each to a random site dynamically fetched from the server. After detecting that they are links, which I can do, how would I make those tappable?

I have scoured StackOverflow, there have been no duplicates or this question, that I can find. If you find something exactly like this question, feel free to mark it as a duplicate. All I’ve seen were people recommending to use a `UITextView`, a 3rd party framework, or to use attributed strings, but the links are known at that point, they aren’t dynamically fetched.

Comment: Attributed strings should work

Comment: @aheze Right now I am able to use an attributed string to color and underline the links in the label. But how would you go about making those tappable? Each individual link? So if the string is “Follow me on google.com and facebook.com” - how would I only make the links in the attributed string, tappable?

Comment: You could probably use regex to match strings like "google.com", then create a URL for it. Then, make an attributed string using that URL.

Comment: @aheze correct, I understand. I am able to do that now using `NSDataDetector`. My question is, how do I make each individual link tappable in a `UILabel` with multiple links?

Comment: Can I see your code so far with `NSDataDetector`?

Comment: @Michael - is there a specific reason you don't want to use a `UITextView`? If you disable editing and scrolling, you get what is effectively a multi-line label, and you can set it to detect links.

Comment: @DonMag rookie mistake on my part ‍♂️ It was because of issues I was having it resize in a stackView. But disabling scrolling fixed that! Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DonMag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag) pointed out, in the comments of the question - I could in fact use a `UITextView`, and disabling scrolling, which fixed the original reason I was having, that made me turn to do it with a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it with a UILabel class then:

- set 'isUserInteractionEnabled' property to true
- create a Tap Gesture Recogniser and assign it to the gesture recognisers collection outlet of the label
- write 'IBAction func didTapLink(_ sender: Any)' which opens a selected link and connect is with the tap gesture recogniser 'sent action selector' outlet
- set 'text' property with a link

if you must to display a link as in a browser then:

- set 'attributedText' property with a link
- add 'NSAttributedString.Key.link' attribute to the link range